# Executing commands in Series

Tags: function, arduino, command

This is from my arduino code. What do you place under the receive command to control execution of the commands in a series operating process? Thank you in advance.

```
void loop(void) 
{
  char cmd(C,S,V,T);
    //what do i put here//

if (cmd=='C')

      Serial.println("complete");


if (cmd=='S')
      Serial.println("incomplete");


else if (cmd=='V')
      Serial.println("wrong");


else if (cmd=='T')

      Serial.println("correct");


else
      Serial.println("retry"); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works; I just tried it.

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(100); //don't wait longer than 100ms for incoming data
}

void loop(void)
{
  char cmd;
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    cmd = Serial.read();  
    if (cmd == 'C')
    {
      Serial.println("complete");
    }
    else if (cmd == 'S')
    {
      Serial.println("incomplete");
    }
    else if (cmd == 'V')
    {
      Serial.println("wrong");
    }
    else if (cmd == 'T')
    {
      Serial.println("correct");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("retry");
    }
  }
}
```